# Name dynamically created textarea

Tags: javascript, textarea

Beginner out of my depth here! Im trying to create textareas of which i can then send the vales of to a database. Im having trouble naming the text areas. Heres what i have tried . . .

```
var node = document.createElement("textarea");
var textnode = document.createTextNode("Comment"); 

node.appendChild(textnode);  

node.setAttribute("id", "commen");
node.setAttribute("name", "comment");

textnode.attr('name', 'com');
textnode.style.width ="100%";

textnode.rows = "400";
textnode.cols ="50";
textnode.id = "myTextArea";
textnode.name = "comments";
textnode.value = "commenters";

node.setAttribute("align", "center");
node.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");                               

textnode.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");    

var answerBox = document.getElementById("Answer");
answerBox.style.padding = "0px 0px 0px 0px";

answerBox.setAttribute("align", "center");
answerBox.appendChild(node);
```

I cant seem to set a name for the dynamically created textarea which is inside "Answer" Div. It does make a taxtarea but there is no name or id attached to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't add attributes to text nodes. They're essentially just text. Set the attributes on `node` and not `textnode`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you remove the text node and attempts to set style on the nodes, [you're left with this](https://jsfiddle.net/3f2kcgnh/4/), which if you inspect using the dev console does have a textarea with both the name and id attached to it:

```js
var node = document.createElement("textarea");
node.setAttribute("id", "commen");
node.setAttribute("name", "comment");
node.setAttribute("align", "center");
node.setAttribute("id", "id_you_like");

var answerBox = document.getElementById("Answer");
answerBox.setAttribute("align", "center");
answerBox.appendChild(node);
```

```html
<div id="Answer"/>
```